# Offline Permission change 5th of may, 2012, publish_stream after the 5th of may 2012

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I used to solve the permission request with this code all the time:

```
<? $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($fanpage_app.'&scope=publish_stream,offline_access&app_data=af'); ... ?>
```

But when Permission dialog is opening, there are no extra permissions displayed, so they are no asked for. How do you ask for permission? Are you using the new auth dialog?

Second is, DO I STILL NEED OFFLINE ACCESS while asking for publish_stream, to post whenever my apps like to post to the feed of the app user?

TIA and cheers,
daniel

Answer (score 0):

TO answer the second part of your question

For all calls to Graph API, you need an `access_token`. `offline_access` guarantees that you have an `access_token` that wont expire. So you don't need `offline_access` to post to Facebook, but that permission will make your life a lot easier for getting non expired access_tokens.

Comment: offline access is deprecated since May 1st.

Comment: @Yan: Not until July 5. `The offline_access permission is deprecated and will be removed July 5, 2012.`